# Isomorphism between $H/H\cap N$ and $HN/N$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Suppose we have a group G under operation +, and let H be a subgroup and N a normal subgroup.
I want to prove that $H/H\cap N$ is isomorphic to $HN/N$.

Where, if I am not mistaken:

- $H/H\cap N = \{H\cap N + h | h \in H\}$
- $HN/N = \{N+(h+n)|h \in H, n \in N\}$

Comment: This is the second group isomorphism theorem. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem. A classical one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compose the maps
$$H\xrightarrow{\text{inclusion}}HN\xrightarrow{\text{quotient}}HN/N$$
Show that the composite map from $H$ to $HN/N$ is surjective. Observe that its kernel is $H\cap N$. Then apply the first isomorphism theorem.

(Incidentally, the fact that $H/(H\cap N)\cong HN/N$ is known as the second isomorphism theorem.)

Comment: Great answer, thanks. But I have a little trouble here. Why can't we say that $HN/N=\{hnN\big| h \in H, n \in N \}=\{hN\big|h \in H\}$ since $nN=N$ for all $n \in N$. And then suddenly it comes to $H/N$(which is not a quotient at all) and not to $H/(N \cap H)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Define $\phi:H \to \frac{HN}{N}$ by $\phi(h)=hN$ and show that this is surjective homomorphism whose kernel is $H\cap N$ and therefore from isomorphism theorem $\frac{H}{H\cap N}$ and $\frac{HN}{N}$ are isomorphic.